# Python generate and return tuples in a non-list form

Tags: python, arrays, list, tuples

```
def tuple_gen(x, y, num):
    pos = []
    for i in range(num):
        x += 1
        pos.append([x, y])
        pos[i] = tuple(pos[i])
    return pos
```

my input is:

```
>>> tuple_gen(0,1,5)
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1)]
```

What I want is to return tuples but not a list:

```
>>> tuple_gen(0,1,5)
(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1)
```

Because I want to form a list that includes different kind of tuples:

```
>>> [tuple_gen(0,1,5), tuple_gen(0,2,6)]
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 2), (6, 2)]
```

I want a short and clearest solution.

*note that I don't want to use any `extend` or `append` to merge those lists because I need so many tuples

Comment: Do you _really_ need that final giant list? It may be better to make an iterator that yields all the tuples you want. BTW, your current version of `tuple_gen` can be done with a simple one-line list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently returning a list of tuples:

```
>>> tuple_gen(0,1,5)
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1)]
```

You could return a tuple of tuples with `return tuple(pos)`.

That is what you asked for, but it won't help you for this use case:

```
[tuple_gen(0,1,5), tuple_gen(0,2,6)]
```

That will still be a list of two tuples of tuples.

What you really need is to return a list, as you do, and then concatenate those lists later:

```
tuple_gen(0,1,5) + tuple_gen(0,2,6)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that exactly as you said, But you have some options, first is chaining the result of your functions:

```
>>> a = [(1, 1), (2, 1)]
>>> b = [(3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1)]
>>> 
>>> a + b
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1)]
>>> # Or using itertools.chain
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> 
>>> list(chain(a, b))
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1)]
```

Secondly if you are in python3.5+ you can use advanced unpacking:

```
>>> a = [(1, 1), (2, 1)]
>>> b = [(3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1)]
>>> [*a, *b]
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1)]
```

Which for functions you can do:

```
[*tuple_gen(0,1,5), *tuple_gen(0,2,6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a container, which holds your tuples. You are thinking of list or scheme like tuples, which are linked lists. The tuples in python are expensive in creating, joining and appending. You should use lists for this purposes. You can take an list and just join it.

```
tuple_gen(0,1,5) + tuple_gen(0,2,6)
```

Or you can join your tuples outsite your gen function.

```
def tuple_gen(x, y, num):
    for i in range(num):
        x += 1
        yield (x,y)

x = []
for i in tuple_gen(0,1,5):
    x.append(i)

for i in tuple_gen(0,2,6):
    x.append(i)
```

There are other container for python - even a linked list. Almost all are implemented as a list with some additionals.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the way you're calling `tuple_gen`. Here's an example, with a slightly improved version of `tuple_gen`:

```
def tuple_gen(x, y, num):
    pos = []
    for i in range(num):
        x += 1
        pos.append((x, y))
    return pos

bases = (
    (0, 1, 5), 
    (0, 2, 6),
)

a = [t for args in bases for t in tuple_gen(*args)] 
print(a)
```

**output**

```
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 2), (6, 2)]
```

An alternative is to create a generator that yields all the desired tuples:

```
def make_tuples(bases):
    for x, y, num in bases:
        yield from ((i, y) for i in range(x + 1, num + x + 1))

bases = (
    (0, 1, 5), 
    (0, 2, 6),
)

a = list(make_tuples(bases))
print(a)
```

Depending on your actual needs, you may be able to avoid creating a list (thus saving RAM) and just use the tuples as they are created. Eg,

```
for t in make_tuples(bases):
    print(t)
```

**output**

```
(1, 1)
(2, 1)
(3, 1)
(4, 1)
(5, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 2)
(3, 2)
(4, 2)
(5, 2)
(6, 2)
```